# Outputting issue in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

Currently my code is this.

```
resultLbl BYTE  "Coin Information", 0
sum     BYTE    "Number of Coins: ", 0
NumberOfDollars BYTE    "Dollars: ", 0
NumberOfCents   BYTE    "Cents: ", 0

        dtoa    sum, ebx       ; convert to ASCII characters
        dtoa    NumberOfDollars, ecx    ; convert to ASCII characters
        dtoa    NumberOfCents, edx      ; convert to ASCII characters
        output  resultLbl, sum        ; output label and sum
```

I'm having an issue because the way I want it to output is a single window, but 3 different lines. I don't know how to output on three seperate lines. 
Here is how I would like my output to look.

Coin Information

Number of Coins: 50

Number of Dollars: 5

Number of Cents: 30

Can anyone help? This is really bugging me

Comment: For assembly you need to mention what CPU (family) you're talking about

Comment: 80x86 architecture if that's what you're asking

Comment: That does not look like x86.  What are you assembling your code with?

Comment: Are `dtoa` and `output` macros? If they are, we need to see them too, since we have no idea what this code is doing. If they aren't, then this isn't x86.

Comment: @ughoavgfhw: They are obviously masm macros. @Paul&Michael: the architecture or assembler have no importance here. We need to know the OS to add the correct line return characters. But since it's masm, then all the information is in the question. :)

Comment: masm isn't even mentioned in the question and it's not tagged as such - I will fix the tags

Answer (score 0):

```
resultLbl BYTE  "Coin Information", 0
sum     BYTE    "Number of Coins: ", 0
NumberOfDollars BYTE    "Dollars: ", 0
NumberOfCents   BYTE    "Cents: ", 0
```

You are terminating your strings with no additional character.

Try this:

```
resultLbl BYTE  "Coin Information",0Dh,0Ah,0
sum     BYTE    "Number of Coins: ",0Dh,0Ah,0
NumberOfDollars BYTE    "Dollars: ",0Dh,0Ah,0
NumberOfCents   BYTE    "Cents: ",0Dh,0Ah,0
```